# How to convert a C ternary statement into an if/else if declared within an if condition?

Tags: c, if-statement, microcontroller, ternary-operator

So after looking on the massive interweb, I was unable to find an answer to this.

Say I have this piece of code:

```
if(P4IN & GPIO_PIN1?0:1){
        if (state==1){
            state = 0;
            //Wait for this state to pass -- ends up saving the current state on button press.
            while (counter < 10000){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        else{
            state = 1;
            while (counter < 10000){
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I rewrite this so that `if(P4IN & GPIO_PIN1?0:1)` is not written like this. I do not mind creating extra if/else conditions or extending this block of code (intended for the MSP432)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `if(P4IN & GPIO_PIN1?0:1)` -> `if (!(P4IN & GPIO_PIN1))`

Comment: ...and you should (probably) manage debouncing if input pin is conncted to an external switch

Comment: Note that `&` has higher precedence than the ternary, so the original statement could have used some parens to be clearer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simplify the whole thing to this:

```
if (!(P4IN & GPIO_PIN1)) {
  state = !state;

  while (counter < 10000) {
    counter++;
  }
}
```